# Latexmk script could not be found

Tags: miktex, windows

So I use Atom for my editing of latex documents and their plugin says that Texify is no longer supported. Before this bites me (I'm still relatively new to LaTeX so I save/build after every few commands I add), I want to make sure to get latexmk working on my computer.

I've installed a Perl interpreter (ActiveState Perl) and when I invoke perl from a commandline, it works fine. However, when I try to run latexmk, I get thrown the following error message.

```
latexmk.exe: The script could not be found.
latexmk.exe: Data: scriptEngine="perl", name="latexmk", path="scripts/latexmk/perl/latexmk.pl"
```

I used the MiKTeX package manager and made sure to run it as an administrator, and it installs fine (I can manually verify the existence of the script it's looking for in E:\LaTeX\scripts\latexmk\perl\latexmk.pl), but it just won't run.

I'm not entirely sure why it's not working, but I have a hunch that it's due to the fact Perl is installed on my C:\ drive, while MiKTeX is installed on my E:\ drive.

Comment: Are you sure that the perl script is in scripts\latexmk\ **perl** \latexmk.pl? I just run a small test and miktex installed scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl which would be wrong.

Comment: I just ran an update and the correct location of the perl script is now in `scripts/latexmk/latexmk.pl`. Run the update manager (amin **and** user mode).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a solution. I downloaded the latexmk sourcefiles from this link: [personal.psu.edu/jcc8//software/latexmk-jcc/latexmk-448.zip](http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8//software/latexmk-jcc/latexmk-448.zip)

I unzipped the file that I downloaded, and then I copied `latexmk.pl` and `latexmk.bat` to the directory of the error. In my case the error directory was `scripts/latexmk/perl/latexmk.pl` I had to create the `latexmk/perl/` directory under `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts`

Then I copied the 2 files to the following directory: `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexmk\perl` And then I ran the MikTex update (admin) tool that came with the installation of MikTeX. I rebooted my computer and then my TexStudio was able to compile the file with latexmk.

Comment: Worked brilliantly, thanks! Also have to make sure perl is actually installed on the system and in the environment variables path.

Comment: What do you mean under "then I ran MikTex update (admin)". I have just tried to update, but I am getting `get host by name failed in tcp_connect()` error. Maybe that `s because of MikTex site fallen a week ago

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem under MiKTeX 2.9. It seems that the *latexmk* binary was available on my system (in `Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/latexmk`), but the MiKTeX package manager was not listing the corresponding package as installed. I installed the package through the package manager, and the problem was solved.